# XML/XSLT putting subnode elements to upper level

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been looking for solutions to fix a problem that I have with my xml file. I want to edit it using xslt. I'm looking to put the elements contained in  to the upper node, so they will be at the same level that "id" and "date".

```html
<test>
- <invoice>
  <id>163-01</id>
  <date>2016-09-06</date>
    - <order>
      <cadreLegal>LAB</cadreLegal>
      <prestataire>907</prestataire>
      <personneProtegee>1951</personneProtegee>
      <dateEtablissement>2016-09-06</dateEtablissement>
      <heureEtablissement>13:22:00</heureEtablissement>
      </order>
 </invoice>
- <invoice>
  <id>163-01</id>
  <date>2016-09-06</date>
    - <order>
      <cadreLegal>LAB</cadreLegal>
      <prestataire>907</prestataire>
      <personneProtegee>1951</personneProtegee>
      <dateEtablissement>2016-09-06</dateEtablissement>
      <heureEtablissement>13:22:00</heureEtablissement>
      </order>
 </invoice>
  </test>
```

This what I want to have.

```html
<test>
- <invoice>
   <id>163-01</id>
   <date>2016-09-06</date>
   <cadreLegal>LAB</cadreLegal>
   <prestataire>907</prestataire>
   <personneProtegee>1951</personneProtegee>
   <dateEtablissement>2016-09-06</dateEtablissement>
   <heureEtablissement>13:22:00</heureEtablissement> 
 </invoice>
- <invoice>
   <id>163-01</id>
   <date>2016-09-06</date>
   <cadreLegal>LAB</cadreLegal>
   <prestataire>907</prestataire>
   <personneProtegee>1951</personneProtegee>
   <dateEtablissement>2016-09-06</dateEtablissement>
   <heureEtablissement>13:22:00</heureEtablissement>
 </invoice>
</test>
```

I tried several code using xslt but I never been able to get what I want. I also tried the solutions found on stackoverflow. Could you please help me fixing this issue?

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="order">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="invoice">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/order"/>
  <xsl:call-template name="test"/>
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you in advance .

Rflow

Comment: "*I tried several code using xslt*" Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a newbie with xslt. Most of the code that I tried were exemple found online that I modified to fit to my example.

Comment: I added one the code that I used, I'm still confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to copy everything as is, except for `order` -  where you only want to copy its children, not itself:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it tommorow ( the files are not on this computer). I will get the same results as  my second xml code ?